# Query android user dictionary return nothing

Tags: android, dictionary, cursor

I'm trying query words from UserDicionary but nothing is returned. What I'm doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, 
                new String[] {UserDictionary.Words.WORD}, null, null, null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while(cursor.moveToNext())
        {
                        //nothing is logged...
            Log.d("Palavra", cursor.getString(0));          
        }
```